# Terms and Condition checkout Magento 2 not saving the value into the databse

Tags: database, magento, magento2, checkout, magento-2.3

I have configured terms and condition properly from the Magento admin section.
In the checkout, the checkbox is present. I would like to know where the agreement values are store in the database after the checkout.
I see checkout_agreement and checkout_agreement_store well populated, but in sales_order the are no connection to those table. There are no less other tables that can help to find that the checkbox had been checked.
I'm using Mangento 2.3.6 and i cannot update it.

**
If by default that value is not stored anyware, how can i store it in order to retrive it in the future?
I cannot install payment plugins
**

Thank you

In short:
Find table or colums where i can associate customer_id, store_id, agreement_id, order_id and the value of my customs Terms And Codition.
If what i'm looking for does not exists i need a custom solution and how to make it store that value.